# Combining two or more Worksheet_Change Event in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sets of codes to run on VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    If Target.Value < 20 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(171, 171, 171)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(175, 96, 137)
    End If


   End If
    
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    If Target.Value < 20 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(171, 171, 171)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(175, 96, 137)
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I can't use both codes because of ambiguous Worksheet_Change in VBA. Is there any other way where I can run both codes without showing any error?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both sets of code like this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value < 20 Then
            Me.Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(171, 171, 171)
        Else
            Me.Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(175, 96, 137)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't `If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then` and `If Target.Value < 20` assume that `Target` is a single cell?